# \color makes my text not aligned in table header

Tags: tables, color, rowcolor

I'm trying to make my entire header row colored with `\rowfont` but when I do the top ruler is is to far above the contents of the row. I've narrowed the problem down to `\color` like in the MWE below, but this is as far as I've come (See "Version" and compare to "Date" in the image below).

How do I change the color of the text without changing the text padding/height/alignment or whatever the problem is?

EDIT: Removed tabu package since it's broken. I still have the same problem though. Also note that removing resizebox does not change the issue at hand.

```latex
% !TeX program = lualatex
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
\documentclass[varwidth=true, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{568CA3} %my blue

\begin{document}

\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tabular}{@{}p{20mm}p{25mm}p{30mm}p{30mm}p{30mm}@{}}
        %\rowfont{\color{primary}}
        \toprule
        {\color{primary} Version} & Date & Author & Reviewed~by & Approved~by \\
        \midrule
        1.0 & \today & Me & Someone else & A boss
        %\bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Table with 'Version' not aligned]

Comment: Don't use the tabu package. It is in various places broken and coloring tables don't work reliably. See the readme and the issues here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu. And don't use resizebox with a tabular, this gives quite uneven font sizes and looks bad.

Comment: As an alternative to tabu, you can use tabularx

Comment: Edited question to remove `tabu` package. Same problem though.

Comment: Add `\leavevmode` before `\color`

Comment: What about `\textcolor{primary}{Version}`?

Comment: What's the reason for the `p` type columns?  As it is, it seems as if you wouldn't need any linebreaks inside of table cells, so `l` type columns should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reproduce the problem with simpler code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{primary}{HTML}{568CA3} %my blue

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}% just for the example

\begin{document}

\fbox{\parbox[t]{20mm}{Version}}\quad
\fbox{\parbox[t]{20mm}{\textcolor{primary}{Version}}}\quad
\fbox{\parbox[t]{20mm}{\color{primary}Version}}\quad
\fbox{\parbox[t]{20mm}{\noindent\color{primary}Version}}

\end{document}
```

A `p{<length>}` column is essentially `\parbox[t]{<length>}`.

Moral of the story: never initiate a parbox with a `\color` command.

[image]

For the problem at hand, why not using `\rowcolor` with `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`?